# if background = url() - issue on IE

Tags: javascript, if-statement, background, velocity.js

I am trying to achieve a situation where an animation is triggered if an element has a particular `background = url(" ")`. I am using velocity.js as the animation plugin and am able to achieve this no problem on all browser except IE, in which it fails to recognise the background url in the if statement.

I have two examples in the code below.

The first one (the orange square) uses -

```
if (box.style.background == "orange")
    { run(); }
```

to determine whether to run the animation. IE is fine with this.

However the second (the pink triangle) uses -

```
if (triangle.style.background == "url(http://garyvoss.co.uk/images/triangle.svg) no-repeat")
    { runTriangle(); }
```

to determine whether to run the animation. IE is the only browser not to run this.

Does anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong here.

[JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/garyvoss/8og3pxds/)

HTML

```
<div id="box"></div>

<div id="triangle"></div>
```

CSS

```
#box {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute; }

#triangle {
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
top: 120px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 4; }
```

JS

```
window.setInterval(function runAll() {

var box = document.getElementById('box');

box.style.background = "orange";

function run() {
    Velocity(box, {left: 300}, {easing: "easeInOutQuad", duration: 1000, delay: 0});
    Velocity(box, {left: 10}, {easing: "easeInOutQuad", duration: 1000, delay: 0});
    }

if (box.style.background == "orange")
{ run(); } 

var triangle = document.getElementById('triangle');

triangle.style.background = "url(http://garyvoss.co.uk/images/triangle.svg) no-repeat";

function runTriangle() {
    Velocity(triangle, {left: 300}, {easing: "easeInOutQuad", duration: 1000, delay: 200});
    Velocity(triangle, {left: 10}, {easing: "easeInOutQuad", duration: 1000, delay: 0});
    }

if (triangle.style.background == "url(http://garyvoss.co.uk/images/triangle.svg) no-repeat")
{ runTriangle(); } 

}, 1000);

runAll();
```

Comment: Did you check what `triangle.style.background` looks like on IE? That's very likely the problem. Compound properties can be tricky. I'd probably look at `backgroundImage` and `backgroundRepeat` individually. For that matter, I'd probably use classes.

Answer (score 0):

The URLs in IE are different from webkit and/or Gecko, it is not safe to base your logic on the url paths.

```
if (triangle.style.background == "url(http://garyvoss.co.uk/images/triangle.svg) no-repeat" || triangle.style.background == 'url("http://garyvoss.co.uk/images/triangle.svg") no-repeat' )
{ runTriangle(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find a convoluted way around the issue.

Using .match I can identify a section of the url path and apply that to the if statement so that if that section is present then the animation runs.

I've create a third example (the green circle) in this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/garyvoss/ah1we9g8/) that shows how it works.

```
var str = circle.style.background; 
var res = str.match(/circle/g);
document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = res;

if (document.getElementById("check").innerHTML === "circle")
{ runCircle(); }
```